# How to check image sizes match between densities?

Tags: android

How can I check that if I add a `32x32` image to the `drawable-mdpi` folder an image with the same name and a size of `48x48` is included in the `drawable-hdpi` folder?

Can I make Proguard or Android Studio check this?
Should I build a custom script?

Answer (score 1):

I use [AndroidAssetStudio](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/) to get different resolution images , launcher icons and notification icons. Its will give you all the desired resolution images in different folders i.e (mdpi,xdpi,xxdpi etc) you just need to copy paste it in your "res" folder.